# Count numbers with prime digit

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, primes

Given a number N I need to find the count of the numbers that have atleast one prime digit (2,3,5 or 7) from 1 to N.

Now N can be upto 10^18.What is the best approach to solve this problem.

**Example :** Let N = 100 the answer is 64.

Please help to solve this problem.

**Code :** This is main function.But obviously not good approach

```
    long long int n;
    cin>>n;
    long long int count=0;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        long long temp=i;
        while(temp>0){
            int rem=temp%10;
            if(rem==2 || rem==3 ||rem==5 || rem==7){
                count++;
                break;
            }
            temp=temp/10;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @KerrekSB N will be entered as input and can vary from 1 to 10^18

Comment: Why downvote?Had i done something wrong ?

Comment: This looks like a reasonable approach. There are a few spots where I'd make some style changes, such as saying `temp/=10` instead of the Fortran-like `temp=temp/10`.

Comment: @Logicrat But N can be upto 10^16.So i need better than O(N) approach

Comment: @Logicrat Yeah.So any better approach?Also can i know the reason for downvote ?

Comment: Sounds a lot like a [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/) problem. Know that this is cheating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You think this problem needs programming!!

Use mathematics for the answer.

Consider the complementary problem i.e. there is no prime digits in the number. So you can only use digits `{0, 1, 4, 6, 8, 9}`.

For example How many 2-digits numbers can you make by this set? The answer is `6*6=6^2=36`. If `N` is `100`, the answer is `100-36=64`.

In a simple case if `N` is power of `10` then the answer is `N - 6^log(N)`.

Now how about `N` is not power of `10`. Consider `N=57`. In this case when the first digits is lower than `5`. You can use `{0, 1, 4}` for the first digit and `{0, 1, 4, 6, 8, 9}` for the second one. Therefor answer is `57-3*6+1=40`. (Zeros is excluded in the main question, so the answer is increamented).

Comment: But N need not be power of 10 .Then what?

Comment: For this question you should know a critical note. For generating those numbers that meet the condition you are allowed to use only choose digits from set {0, 1, 4, 6, 8, 9}. Got the answer or need more explanation?

Comment: Please elaborate a bit

Comment: @NematollahZarmehi It is rather simple when N is a power of 10. But it is not clear how to deal with other cases.

Comment: Ok, for this purpose consider the complementary problem i.e. there is no prime digits in it. So you can only use digits `{0, 1, 4, 6, 8, 9}`. For example How many 2-digits numbers can you make by this set? The answer is `6*6=6^2=36`. Now if N is 100, the answer is `100-36=64`. Consider N=57. In this case when the first digits is lower than 5, you can use `{0, 1, 4}` and `{0, 1, 4, 6, 8, 9}` for the second one. The answer is `57-3*6=39`.

Comment: In the second sentence of the second comment: Replace "meet the condition" with "meet the complementary condition".

Comment: @codertester Did you got it? Is there any problem with the answer?

Comment: The answer for 57 is 40. Because you counted 0(and subtracted it) but it is not in 1..57 range.

Comment: @user2040251 Yes, zero is excluded in the main question. Thanks!

Comment: @NematollahZarmehi: the idea is here, but things become a little more complex when you have to remember the allowed digits, I mean for example with `N = 645` first digit may be one of `{0, 1, 4, 6}`, second digit does depend of the value of the first digit... (only `{0, 1, 4}` for `6` , and also `{6, 8, 9}` for the first digit in `{0, 1, 4}`)...

Comment: @NematollahZarmehi Do you have any answer for question by Jarod42.I have the same question.

Answer (score 1):

quote from comment

> the idea is here, but things become a little more complex when you
>   have to remember the allowed digits, I mean for example with N = 645
>   first digit may be one of {0, 1, 4, 6}, second digit does depend of
>   the value of the first digit... (only {0, 1, 4} for 6 , and also {6,
>   8, 9} for the first digit in {0, 1, 4})

I think you can think of numbers like 675 as 600 + 70 + 5.
Then you calculate separately number of combinations that don't have any prime digit for every component like said in posts above (but we do it only for 0..599, 0..69, 0..5). Then you sum them going from left (600 -> 70 -> 5) as long as first digit of the number is not prime.
So you sum resulting numbers of combinations for 600 and 70 because 6 i not prime, but then you don't add combinations for 5 because 7 is prime (that means every number above and equal 670 have prime digit (7 in this case)). This is number of numbers that don't qualify. You have to substract it from original number.
You also have to add one because you don't want to count 0.

EDIT
I came up with this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
int main()
{
    unsigned long long int number;
    unsigned long long int answer;
    std::cin >> number;
    number += 1; //because we search in range 1..n-1
    std::vector<int> digits;

    unsigned long long int numberCopy = number;
    while(numberCopy)
    {
        int digit = numberCopy % 10;
        digits.push_back(digit);
        numberCopy /= 10;
    }
    std::reverse(digits.begin(), digits.end()); //so digits are in proper order

    int numberOfDigits = digits.size();
    std::vector<unsigned long long int> partialCombinations(numberOfDigits);
    //0, 1,       4,    6,    8, 9
    //0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
    constexpr unsigned long long int nonprimesLessThan[11] = {0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6};
    constexpr bool prime[10] = {false, false, true, true, false, true, false, true, false, false};

    //we consider each digit as highest digit in number such that all elements in digits array after this digit are equal 0 (so with 3 right most digit = 6 we check for combinations lower than 600)
    unsigned long long int multiplayer = 1; //with numbers like 5999999 on every higher decimal place we have nonprimesLessThan[10] times more combinations 5999999 because we consider numbers that are lower (6000000-1 = 5999999)
    for(int i = numberOfDigits - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        int combinations = nonprimesLessThan[digits[i]] * multiplayer;
        partialCombinations[i] = combinations;
        multiplayer *= nonprimesLessThan[10]; //with numbers like 5999999 on every higher decimal place we have nonprimesLessThan[10] times more combinations
    }
    unsigned long long int sumOfCombinations = partialCombinations[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < numberOfDigits; ++i)
    {
        if(prime[digits[i - 1]]) break;
        sumOfCombinations += partialCombinations[i];
    }
    answer = number - sumOfCombinations;
    std::cout << answer;
    return 0;
}
```

I can't explain it more than i did in comments.
I don't know if it is fully correct either but i can't check it.
At least it seems to give good results.

Comment: How are you finding numbers of combinations for 600 and 70

Comment: Basically you want to divide this number to components being in form n*10^m (600+70+5) and do what @Nematollah Zarmehi said for every of them separately. Let's say you save results in a[3]. Then assings to sum a[0]. then for i = 1 to 2 if a[i-1] is not prime sum += a[i].

Comment: @coder tester if you read Nematollah Zarmehi's post and understood it you should be able to do it. I can't explain it better. When i will have some time i may put code.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problems can be solved with pretty standard dynamic programming:

1)Let's construct the number starting from the most significant to the least significant digit. The state is: `(len, was, greater)`, where `len` is the number of digits already processed, `was` is a boolean value which indicates whether 2, 3, 5 or 7 was already added and `greater` is boolean value which is true if `N` is greater than current prefix and false if it is equal to it(note that if the current prefix is greater than `N` then it is invalid).
The value of each state is the number of ways to construct such prefix.

2)Base case: `f(0, 0, 0) = 1`. There is only one way to construct an empty prefix.
To compute other values, one can iterate over `len` and try to add each valid digit.

Here is my C++ code:

```
long long compute(string N) {
    static set<int> good({2, 3, 5, 7});
    int len = N.length();
    vector<vector<vector<long long>>> f(len + 1, 
        vector<vector<long long>>(2, vector<long long>(2)));
    f[0][0][0] = 1; //base case
    for (int i = 1; i <= len; i++)
        for (int was = 0; was <= 1; was++)
            for (int gt = 0; gt <= 1; gt++) 
                for (int d = 0; d <= 9; d++) {
                    bool n_was = was || good.count(d);
                    bool n_gt = false;
                    if (gt) {
                        n_gt = true;
                    } 
                    else {
                        if (N[i - 1] - '0' < d) //Invalid prefix
                            continue;
                        if (N[i - 1] - '0' > d)
                            n_gt = true;
                    }
                    f[i][n_was][n_gt] += f[i - 1][was][gt];
                }
    return f[len][1][0] + f[len][1][1];
}
```

3)The time complexity is `O(length(N))` which is `O(log N)`.

Comment: I am not getting it.Please explain with example or code in c++ so that i can understand in better way

Comment: What is this new_was = was or new_digit in {2, 3, 5, 7} in loop?

Comment: @codertester Assume that N is std::string, f is a std::map from a tuple<int, bool, bool> to long long(it can actually be a 3-d array of long long too); i, L and new_digit are int; was, greater, new_was and new_greater are bool and it will become almost like C++ code.

Comment: Yeah remaining part is ok to me but what is this "new_was = was or new_digit in {2, 3, 5, 7}"?Are you assigning new_was as was?

Comment: @codertester bool new_was = was || new_digit == 2 || new_digit == 3 || new_digit == 5 || new_digit == 7.

Comment: Is it if statement?Means execute below statements if that is true only ?

Comment: @codertester It just a creation of new variable. It is not an if statement.

Comment: @user2040251 is this what you were saying?But its giving runtime error.Here is link to code in c++ :  http://ideone.com/rJd5hz